# how to make automation scrolling with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

as u see in the above image i need to scroll such element with selenium in many place this scrolling needed like in telegram contact list in linkedin when u search for connection everywhere where content is inside some div and user need to scroll that specfic portion of area i need to automate this for my project what i try

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  scroll = driver.find_element_by_class_name('md_modal_list_peer_name')

  scroll.send_keys(Keys.End)

  html = driver.find_element_by_class_name('contacts_modal_members_list')

  #html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
```

Please Help ME ON ThiS

Comment: Why do you need to scroll?

Comment: most of the pages have data in such format and i need to scrape that data too so i think that's answer to your question @DMart

Comment: i think nobody knows this answer everyone want to answer  the same question like how tio scroll the webpage

Comment: To be more precise: Why do you need to scroll the page to access the information in the DOM? Or are you asking more in an "infinite scroll" use case?